# How do I use discord js v-13 reaction collector and buttons

Tags: javascript, async-await, discord.js

```
let list1 = stripIndents `
aaaa
one
`;
let list2 = stripIndents `
aaaa
two
`;

let pages = [list1, list2];
let page = 1;

const embed = new MessageEmbed();
        embed.setTitle('just test');
        embed.setDescription(pages[page - 1]);
        embed.setColor(0x21c400);
        embed.setFooter('this bot is provided by jaguar');
        embed.setTimestamp();


client.on('interactionCreate', async (interaction) => {
if(interaction.customId === 'first'){
    
let message = await interaction.channel.send({ embeds: [embed]})
if (pages.length === 1) return;
await message.react(':red_circle:');
const filter = (reaction, user) => {
    return reaction.emoji.name === ':red_circle:' && user.id === message.author.id;
};
const next = message.createReactionCollector({filter, time: 999999});

next.on('collect', () => {
    console.log('works')})
    } else if (interaction.customId === 'second'){
        interaction.reply({content: `it works son`})
    }
})
```

the next.on collector doesn't work when I react to the emoji I don't get anything in the console even an error,the syntax matches discord.js v-13 exactly

Comment: Do you have the `GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS` intent?

Comment: ```const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: 
[Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES,Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS] });
```
yes i have these intents

Answer (score 1):

First thing I check if a collector doesn't fire is either I had a return above it
or in your case wrong filter, lets take a look at your filter
`return reaction.emoji.name === '' && user.id === message.author.id;`
the reaction.emoji.name is the emoji name without :: if the emoji is **Custom**
or the unicode if the emoji is original like what you have, check https://emojipedia.org/
anyways the emoji unicode you want is